# white space between html element and div

Tags: html, css

I am using an html element:

```
<div class="sample">
<p>hello</p>
</div>
```

But I don't want any white space in between `<p>` and `<div>` tag.

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: show relevant CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write the code in a `single line`,

```
<div class="sample"><p>hello</p></div>
```

Comment: @user3122093 This is a generic fix. By the way are you using any other css properties.?

Comment: No I am not using any CSS property

Answer (score 1):

use `white-space:nowrap` and `margin:0`  

[**check demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/L94LM/1/)

```
<div class="sample">
   <p>hello inside p tag</p>
   hello
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
p {
    margin:0;
}
div.sample {
    border:1px solid #000;
    min-width:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't seem like coming from a bad account. +1! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard : thankx mate...it *is* coming from a gud account, bad account is minor-part of it now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="sample" style="white-space:nowrap">
<p>Your Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` has no default margin or padding. So there souldn't be any space *between* them.

If you want, you can override the default *margin* of the `<p>` tag with

```
p
{ 
   margin:0;
}
```

PS:

The body tag also has a default margin, perhaps that's what you need to get rid of:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/FtYfs/)**

```
body
{
    margin:0;
}
```